# TListView & selection highlighting

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, tlistview

Is there any (easy) way to suppress the blue selection of a selected TListView item (VCL)?

[image]

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can make the highlighting less prominent using `RowSelect`, `HideSelection` and the like.

Comment: @UliGerhardt setting `HideSelection` to **true** and deselecting the ListView by `Form->ActiveControl = 0;` is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but there is still the selection color for the time the mouse is down. And the ListView will get back its focus as soon as I un-focus/re-focus the Form itself.
@Spektre due to the many subitems and features like checkboxes I want to avoid to do custom drawing, which would require lots of coding :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `OnSelectItem()` event, set `Selected := False;`. Alternatively also `Focused:=False;` for the `Item` parameter.

```
procedure TForm10.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
begin
//  item.Focused:=False;
  item.selected:=False;
end;
```

[image]

If you don't want to see the focus rectangle either, uncomment the first line in the code.

Comment: ...and by storing the TListItem in a class member I still can access the previously selected TListItem in OnClick. I knew there was a simple solution, but somehow my synapses were deadlocked :). Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried it but won't this make the listview unusable for keyboard users?

Comment: @Uli You mean because not knowing what is selected, I assume? Yes, but that is why you can leave the focus rectangle on. Personally, I would use this only for display, and not for selection at all.

Comment: I was concerned about toggling the checkboxes via space bar and the like. I just tested it and it works.